# Relationship between thermionic effect and photoelectric effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I have recently come across the thermionic effect, which, I understand, is the emission of ions from a metalic cathode once it is heated up due to the energy that is conferred to said cathode. If the freed charges are electrons, I imagine it as the electron cloud in the metal being excited due to the heat, and oscillating with a bigger amplitude each time until some of them are energetic enough in order to escape the metal. This reminds me a lot of the photoelectric effect, as electrons are emitted from a metalic cathode when it is exposed to a source of energy. Could it be that the photoelectric effect is an extreme case of the thermionic effect? As I see it, photons colliding against the metalic cathode increase the energy of the electrons that absorb them, which makes them oscillate more energetically. However, if said photons were energetic enough, then one oscillation would suffice for the electron to be freed from the atom, which explains why photoelectrons are freed in under $10^{-9} (s)$.

Please let me know what you think and, if I'm wrong, which is probably the case, please correct me. Thanks in advance!